# React-Native-Popup-Menu and Stack Navigator

Tags: react-native-popup-menu

ReactNavigation Stack Navigator has the property HeaderRight useful to place the menu button in the header, but has not a context menu.

Is it possible to integrate the React Native Popup Menu in the Stack Navigator?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please make the question clearer? You should also share a piece of code, of what you've tried.

Comment: should be possible. what exactly is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely possible to accomplish.  In your root App do the following:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { MenuContext } from 'react-native-popup-menu';
import MainNavigator from './components/MainNavigator';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MenuContext>
        <MainNavigator />
      </MenuContext>
    );
  }
}
```

Then the way you've implemented your `headerRight` should work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I set the navigationOptions of StackNavigator setting my custom button as RightHeader

```
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
title: `${navigation.state.params.Name}`,
headerRight: (
      <ContextMenuButton
      />)
```

I would like to know if it is possible to use the React Native Popup Menu, display and use it in combination with the headerRight

Answer (score 0):

I've been wondering about this as well, and found a solution:
Generally, all the Menu parts **have to** be inside of the `Menu` tag, so the `MenuTrigger` as well.
You can style the `MenuTrigger` but I didn't get it into the top bar with that.

Good news: It's even easier than that, simply place the whole `Menu` into your `navigationOptions` like this:

```
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
  title: 'Uploaded Videos',
  drawerLockMode: 'locked-closed',
  headerRight: 
    <Menu renderer={SlideInMenu} style={{ zIndex: 10 }}>
      <MenuTrigger text="open menu"/>
      <MenuOptions style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Text>Menu</Text>
        <MenuOption onSelect={() => { console.log("clicked") text="Click me" />
      </MenuOptions>
    </Menu>
```

Caveat: `navigationOptions` are static, so in your menu you can't use functions of the component. But there are ways around that, see for one example [this issue at react-native-navigation](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/147). Generally, you should probably use redux for that.

Hopefully this still helps you!